# Place a complete bed using /setblock

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am setting up different means of transportation on our server. Right now I'm building an airship with four cabins. In each cabin is a bed. The idea is that each room has a different destination and when you sleep in the bed it teleports you to the same room in a duplicate of that airship at the destination area (to make it like you're really travelling in the ship).

I tried teleporting a sleeping player (using `{Sleeping:1b}`) but the sleeping animation continued and then moved the player back to the original bed. I corrected this by destroying the bed before teleporting and that fixed it however now I have another issue resulting from that. I replace the bed with `/setblock` and it only places the foot of the bed.

How can I use a command block to replace the bed so that both the foot and head of the bed are present?

Comment: It might be easier to `clone` a bed instead.  I'm sure it's possible to `setblock` a bed, but it will take at least two commands, and I don't know how to do it offhand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to use two commands; one to set the foot part, one to set the head part. To setblock the head part of the bed, add 8 to the dataValue you used for the foot part.

For example, these two commands will create a bed facing north:

```
/setblock 0 64 0 bed 0
/setblock 0 64 1 bed 8
```

Or these two for a bed facing east:

```
/setblock 0 64 0 bed 3
/setblock 1 64 0 bed 11
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Minecraft 1.16.1:

```
/setblock -50 62 18 minecraft:cyan_bed[part=foot,facing=south]
/setblock -50 62 19 minecraft:cyan_bed[part=head,facing=south]
```

(this based partly on https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/comments/du596f/how_do_i_place_a_full_bed_with_setblock/)