# Place a bed with setblock: "minecraft:bed" is unknown

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've read [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/231180/minecraft-command-blocks-place-a-complete-bed-using-setblock) but the solution doesn't work, I get: `bloc type "minecraft:bed" is unknown`.

How to circumvent this?

I'm playing Minecraft 1.13.

Comment: Have you tried "white_bed"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The different editions of Minecraft have different command IDs.

The Bedrock Edition still uses `minecraft:bed`

However, the Java edition now has different color beds, which are part of the ID: `minecraft:red_bed`

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bed/ID)